# Connect SQL IDE to docker db container?

Tags: sql, docker, ide

I am using docker with three services:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nz01
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: dz01
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
    expose:
      - "8000"
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: pz01
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

All seems to work pretty well, and I know that db service is running on `172.18.0.2` but when I use `Datagrip` to connect to the `DB` to work faster with table creation and inserts and things like that It does not work.

My configuration at django app is:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'pz01',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

The configuration at Datagrip:

```
'DB_NAME': 'postgres',
'USER': 'postgres',
'HOST': 'pz01',
'PORT': 5432,
```

I also tried with host as the ip, and localhost and neither works.
The password as null, because the db service log shows that by default it does not have password.

How can I connect to my docker db from my macbook?

**EDIT:**
As @Dihgg says I fixed the port at DB service.

I set at

```
db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: pz01
    ports:
     - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

The port is not 5432:5432 because when this is the value I get:

```
ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint pz01 (146bb3cdada29f75766aa888143b4af17b267d13096db60fb0ccdaedb710e77e): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:5432 failed: port is already allocated'
    ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Despite that, I can't connect from Datagrip, when I use pz01 as host the error is(trying with 5432 or 5433 port and no password set):

```
Host is unknown
```

When I use as host the ip the error is: `Connection failed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try expose the port in the db container

```
db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: pz01
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
    - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

And then, use the localhost:5432 to connect

Comment: Done! I edited my question with the error i get, now i will try another port to solve!

Comment: @Maik Do another port use fixed the problem?

Comment: And, why  using  the `pz01` for the host?  why not `localhost`?

Comment: The host was a test that I did to ensure that it was not the problem.

Comment: referring the port test, I will try later and tell you. But I have a question, what does it mean 5432:5432? This means that the host 5432 port redirects to 5432 database port? Which should I change? I understand that inly the first that refers to host because the other services try to connect through 5432